# IntelliJ IDEA SSH configuration : Sessionfactory cannot be create successfully

Tags: java, intellij-idea, ssh

When I try to use the Persistence tool to generate Java classes and persistence metadata for the database schema, an error message shows up:

> "Please choose persistence  unit"

But in the spring-config.xml, `<bean id="sessionFactory"/>` has been created by the tool. I don't know what is wrong.

A picture of this error:

[image]

Comment: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-80833